# FirebaseMessaging flutter errors

Tags: flutter, android-studio, dart, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have four errors and all of them are in one file, minus the 50 depredations
I was working on upgrading my redundancies and deprecated codes
and got stuck at this, I have no idea how to manage firebaseMessaging.

At the moment using android studio flutter
my coding level is beginner, as the codes in the program was done by someone else

Please have a look at the attached image of the error

[firebase](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b8UhH.jpg)

Comment: Check out [ask] to improve this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update this line:

```
final FirebaseMessaging firebaseMessaging = FirebaseMessaging();
```

to this:

```
final FirebaseMessaging firebaseMessaging = FirebaseMessaging.instance;
```

And update this:

```
firebaseMessaging.requestNotificationPermissions(const IosNotificationSettings(sound: true, badge: true, alert: true));
```

to this:

```
firebaseMessaging.requestPermission(sound: true, badge: true, alert: true);
```

Checkout the [documentation](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/messaging/usage).

Comment: I really appreciate your help Victor, I was pulling my hair.

Is it possible to look at this for me. I have replaced this codes 

      _firebaseMessaging.configure(
        onMessage: notificationOnMessage,
        onLaunch: notificationOnLaunch,
        onResume: notificationOnResume,

To -- _firebaseMessaging.configure Error (red line under configure)

FirebaseMessaging.onMessage.listen((RemoteMessage message) {
        RemoteNotification notification = message.notification;
        AndroidNotification android = message.notification?.android;
      });

Is it correct?

Comment: Hi, @AbdulbariMohamed, could you create a new question for this and paste the link here ?

Comment: HI Victor please have a look, I have created a new post 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68342055/firebasemessaging-configure