# firebaseMessaging configure

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-cloud-messaging

I know the firebaseMessaging.configure is deprectated and I am trying to switch to the new format
since the OnMessage, OnLaunch and OnResume are all on the same line I was struggling to achieve this
I came accross some references but not sure how to combine the three in one like the previous one, not sure if I am supposed to do that

Images bellow for before and after

```
void configureFirebase(FirebaseMessaging _firebaseMessaging) {
    try {


      _firebaseMessaging.configure(
          onMessage: notificationOnMessage,
          onLaunch: notificationOnLaunch,
          onResume: notificationOnResume,


      /*  FirebaseMessaging.onMessage.listen((RemoteMessage message) {
        RemoteNotification notification = message.notification;
        AndroidNotification android = message.notification?.android;
      });

     FirebaseMessaging.onMessageOpenedApp.listen((RemoteMessage message) {
        print('A new onMessageOpenedApp event was published!');
        Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/message',
            arguments: MessageArguments(message, true)); 

      });

       */





    } catch (e) {
      print(CustomTrace(StackTrace.current, message: e));
      print(CustomTrace(StackTrace.current, message: 'Error Config Firebase'));
    }
  }

  Future notificationOnResume(Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
    print(CustomTrace(StackTrace.current, message: message['data']['id']));
    try {
      if (message['data']['id'] == "orders") {
        settingRepo.navigatorKey.currentState
            .pushReplacementNamed('/Pages', arguments: 2);
      } else if (message['data']['id'] == "messages") {
        settingRepo.navigatorKey.currentState
            .pushReplacementNamed('/Pages', arguments: 3);
      }
    } catch (e) {
      print(CustomTrace(StackTrace.current, message: e));
    }
  }

  Future notificationOnLaunch(Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
    String messageId = await settingRepo.getMessageId();
    try {
      if (messageId != message['google.message_id']) {
        await settingRepo.saveMessageId(message['google.message_id']);
        if (message['data']['id'] == "orders") {
          settingRepo.navigatorKey.currentState
              .pushReplacementNamed('/Pages', arguments: 2);
        } else if (message['data']['id'] == "messages") {
          settingRepo.navigatorKey.currentState
              .pushReplacementNamed('/Pages', arguments: 3);
        }
      }
    } catch (e) {
      print(CustomTrace(StackTrace.current, message: e));
    }
  }

  Future notificationOnMessage(Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
    Fluttertoast.showToast(
      msg: message['notification']['title'],
      toastLength: Toast.LENGTH_LONG,
      gravity: ToastGravity.TOP,
      timeInSecForIosWeb: 6,
    );
  }
}
```

[image: firebaseMessaging configure]

[image: AFTER]

Comment: I suggest you base your code on the example Flutterfire provides on their GitHub repo. See https://www.github.com/FirebaseExtended/flutterfire/tree/master/packages%2Ffirebase_messaging%2Ffirebase_messaging%2Fexample%2Flib%2Fmain.dart

Comment: Hello @GrahamD I have had a look at it previously but when I copy the codes I get an error like you see on my post 
not sure what part I need and what part I don't

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update the code in the try block to this below:

```dart
FirebaseMessaging.instance.getInitialMessage().then((message) {         
  if (message != null) {
    return notificationOnLaunch(message.data);
  }
});
   
FirebaseMessaging.onMessage
  .listen((RemoteMessage message) => notificationOnMessage(message.data));
    
FirebaseMessaging.onMessageOpenedApp
  .listen((RemoteMessage message) => notificationOnResume(message.data));
```

**Explanation:**

- [FirebaseMessaging.instance.getInitialMessage()](https://pub.dev/documentation/firebase_messaging/latest/firebase_messaging/FirebaseMessaging/getInitialMessage.html) returns a [RemoteMessage](https://pub.dev/documentation/firebase_messaging_platform_interface/latest/firebase_messaging_platform_interface/RemoteMessage-class.html) object when the app is opened from a terminated state via an FCM notification. This replaces `onLaunch`.
- [FirebaseMessage.onMessage](https://pub.dev/documentation/firebase_messaging/latest/firebase_messaging/FirebaseMessaging/onMessage.html) "returns a Stream [of `RemoteMessage`] that is called when an incoming FCM payload is received whilst the Flutter instance is in the foreground." This replaces `onMessage`.
- [FirebaseMessage.onMessageOpenedApp](https://pub.dev/documentation/firebase_messaging/latest/firebase_messaging/FirebaseMessaging/onMessageOpenedApp.html) "returns a Stream [of `RemoteMessage`] that is called when a user presses a notification message displayed via FCM.
  A Stream event will be sent if the app has opened from a background state (not terminated)." This replaces `onResume`.